# How to extract content from a DOM node

Tags: php, dom

I have something like this:

```
$objDom = new DOMDocument();
@$objDom->loadHTML($strHeader);
echo $objDom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0)->c14n();
```

The code is fine but the  tags appear as well. I know I can replace them after but is there a domElement or another method to get this content without the head tags?

**Update:** 
Maybe simplexml or xpath have a better solution for this ?

Comment: Use a user-defined function. Write your this code inside that, find the content using innerHTML or nodeValue, and return it.;)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $objDom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0)->nodeValue
```

**Edit:**

Try http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#101243

Comment: this will not return the html inside only the text

Comment: oh, why don't you say you're parsing html ... okay, a moment

Comment: This is a custom function, I'm looking for something already implemented in PHP, maybe simplexml or xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` like this:

```
echo $objDom->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0)->innerHTML;
```

See the documentation here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML

Comment: innerHTML is not a php dom node property